# R Group by with conditional and sum other columns using data.table

Tags: r, data.table, data-manipulation

I want to sum all columns except one specific column based on the condition by groups.

For example:

```
Col1    Col2   Condition   Name    P1    P2    P3    P4 
1990    1      0           APPLE   10    20    20    30   
1990    1      1           BAN     30    40    50    50   
1990    1      1           CAR     40    40    30    40   
1990    2      0           DOG     100   20    30    40   
1990    2      1           APPLE   10    20    20    30   
1990    2      1           APPLE   50    20    20    30
```

I want to **SUM** `P2`, `P3`, `P4` and then **APPEND** `P1` when `Condition` equals to `"0"` by `Col1` and `Col2`.

So the result will be:

```
Col1    Col2   Condition     P1    P2     P3    P4 
1990    1      0             10    100    100   120     
1990    2      0             100   60     70    100
```

I know how to add in `data.table` but have no idea with this.

```
DT[, .(lapply(.SD, sum, na.rm=TRUE), by=.(Col1, Col2), .SDcols=c("P2", "P3", "P4")]
```

It seems that `DT[, setdiff(names(DT), c("P2", "P3", "P4")), with = FALSE]` is a key but still have no idea.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can group by 'Col1', 'Col2', then `summarise_at` the columns that `starts_with` 'P' (changed to range of columns as per OP's request) to get the `sum` of values where 'Condition' is 0 and then create a 'Condition' column of 0

```
library(dplyr)
df1 %>% 
  group_by(Col1, Col2) %>%
  group_by(P1 = sum(P1[Condition == 0]), add = TRUE) %>% 
  summarise_at(vars(P2:P4), sum) %>%
  mutate(Condition = 0) %>%
  ungroup 
# A tibble: 2 x 7
#   Col1  Col2    P1    P2    P3    P4 Condition
#  <int> <int> <int> <int> <int> <int>     <dbl>
#1  1990     1    10   100   100   120         0
#2  1990     2   100    60    70   100         0
```

---

Or using `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df1)[,  P1 := sum(P1[Condition == 0]), .(Col1, Col2)][, 
     lapply(.SD, sum) , .(Col1, Col2, P1), .SDcols = P2:P4]
```

Comment: is there any `data.table` way? Moreover, `starts_with()` does not work since the column names are different. I just use `P2, P3, P4`, but they are different in reality.

Comment: @PeterChen Are the column names in range

Comment: yes, they are in range. I think `.SDcols = P2:P4` works.

Comment: Can also do in one `[]` by using `c` e.g. `df[, c(P1 = P1[Condition == 0], lapply(.SD, sum)), .(Col1, Col2),
   .SDcols = P2:P4]`